# Why are the times in my local mysql instance saving differently than my live instance?

Tags: mysql, date, timezone, utc

I have a web app using angular, spring, and mysql. When I create a date, for example 2018-11-14 00:00:00, on the front and and save it to my local database it saves as just that. When I do it on the live instance it saves as 2018-11-14 07:00:00. I assuming it has something to do with time zones but I'm assuming both are stored UTC in the database since that is the default (I think). For some reason however it seems that my local instance is just taking the date and storing it while the live instance is converting it to UTC and storing it. I can't imagine this is expected behavior. Could it be something to do with my AWS configuration? My computer?

Comment: There's quite a lot of stuff on timezones here. Have you seen some of that?

Comment: @Strawberry Yes but my application is quite big now with like around 50 different time columns across the database. I am looking for a way to do it without converting individual times or enforcing a specific time zone. I thought understanding why this specifically is happening might lead me to that. If you see a post on how to accomplish that please let me know so I can close this post.